# Force "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" from Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There are many similar questions, but the answers differ from what I am seeing.

This is what I see in Chrome:

A change is made on the server and the client is alerted via AJAX/Javascript to refresh the page.  The client JS attempts location.reload(true).  It refreshes but there are no changes to the page.  I also included the following:

```
window.applicationCache.swapCache();
location.reload(true);
```

That did not help and applicationCache is supposed to be deprecated.

I then tried refreshing the page using a modified URL (appended ?id=122), but it did not correctly refresh.

Manually, I attempted F5 and Control-F5.  Again, there was no change.

In developer mode on Google Chrome, I manually select "Normal Relaod" and "Hard Reload", but no change.  Not until I manually select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" does the updated page correctly display.

How can I programmatically in client JS force the page to refresh using "Empty Cache and Hard reload"?

Comment: Are you sure the change was in the file named in the URL? Maybe it was actually in some other resources, like `.js` or `.css` files that it loads.

Comment: chache busting works by modifying the url of the resource, not the page. example: your js or css can be cache busted by adding `?ver=123456` in the url of the js or css file, but this does not apply to the main .html page.

Comment: I don't think that _javascript_ can control the web browser cache, and I don't see the reason why it should. But if you want to get rid of this problem in the future maybe you can try changing `Cache-Control` headers on server side.

Comment: @Andrej - according to [documentaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#Example) it can

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but the best way I have found since Chrome caches everything to save resources and tries to be smarter than you is to use cache busting.  This can usually be used by adding the "?ver=1234" (increment) or by appending the data to the end of the reference to your JS and CSS reference.  Yes it is not the greatest because it will load the resource every time and not allow the user to cache, meaning slightly longer load times on every page that has the cache busting on it.
But it does work.  You can use the incrementer manually, via JS or your server side code of choice to your JS/CSS reference by adding the "?ver=XXXOrWhateverHere"

Your reference could look like something like this.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/scripts/MyFile.js?ver=12345"></script>`

Or something like this if you want to add it via Javascript (again just one way)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var newDate = new Date();
 var AddJsToHead = document.createElement('script');
 AddJsToHead.type = 'text/javascript';
 AddJsToHead.src = 'https://example.com/scripts/myfile.js?v=' + 
 newDate.getUTCMilliseconds(); 
 document.head.appendChild(AddJsToHead);
 </script>
```

Comment: This did not do anything when I placed it behind the body tag of my page.